# Display Image from Image Library using an SPFX web part

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I'm trying to make an Display Image WP using SPFX. Images are placed in an Image Library. I am having trouble referencing the Image...what am I doing wrong? Thanks...

```
export interface ISPList{
  Title: string;
  Image: ????;
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint picture column contains a Url value and a Description value.You just need to get the Url value in item and set it in  src attribute.

And SharePoint Online has a default image web part in modern page.
[image]